# Changing weights in the deep learning model from hdf5 to tf

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am running a model on Colab pro.

Getting an error:

```
ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 23 layers into a model with 50 layers.
```

This is a common problem, which is still not resolved on GitHub.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10417

My versions

```
Tensorflow version 2.4.0

Keras version 2.4.2
```

My original model works fine, but when I add layers, it fails.

I found the solution here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34016

I change the file from `hdf5` to `tf`

```
weights_path = 'weights'
if not os.path.exists(weights_path):
    os.makedirs(weights_path)
weights_path += '/unet_weights.tf'#.hdf5'
```

My current output looks like

```
Epoch 4/100
42/42 - 142s - loss: 0.1752 - val_loss: 0.2444
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: weights/unet_weights.tf/assets
Epoch 5/100
```

Is it a valid approach?

Comment: best way to find out is to load them. It should work but I have not seen the INFO log line before so even I am curious. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#save_weights also doesn't mention about saving with assets, but its tensorflow so they may have changed it.

Comment: Yeah, take a look at the second link